# Unable to view any tabs in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

I am unable to view any services in my azure portal. A couple of days back everything was visible.

[image]

I think there's some permissions issue. I am logging as Global Admin on the portal.

**[UPDATE]**: I was trying to publish a web application from visual studio to my azure account and when I select my account, it says "There are no Azure subscriptions associated with this account". Is it that my account is suspended or deactivated or so?

Comment: @Jorge, The preview portal says you do not have any subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are signed in to the classic portal with an AAD subscription. These subscriptions don't support using other services. You might be signed in to the wrong directory. Use the "Subscriptions" menu at the top to switch. If you don't have that, you could also be signed in to the wrong account. Some people have used "work/school" (AAD) email addresses to sign up for a "personal" (Microsoft Account) account. If that happens, you'll see a prompt to pick one of the two when you sign in. If you don't see your subscription, it may be assigned to the personal/MSA account. You can grant access to the other one to avoid this.